# Is the compilation of this code standard behaviour?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following code:

```
struct Undefined;

template <typename T>
void TemplateFunction()
{
  Undefined obj;
}

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

I was always under the impression that template functions and template methods (or methods part of a template class) will only be checked for syntax (unless they are instantiated) in which case the above code *should* compile.

Problem is, it does not compile with Xcode (ver: 4.3.2, using the LLVM compiler) and now I am wondering whether the above code is non-standard i.e. it should *not* compile on a compiler conforming to the C++03 standard? The error from Xcode is:

> Variable has incomplete type "Undefined"

Note that in the original code, the undefined object is part of the static assertion.

Comment: [Ideone seems to allow it to compile.](http://ideone.com/PHpFw) (gcc-4.3.4)

Comment: It does compile under g++ 4.6.3 on Linux, and it doesn't under clang++ (though if i understand correctly Xcode uses clang++ too)

Comment: As expected, it compiles with gcc 4.7 and a 4.8 snapshot (linux on x86)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler is right in rejecting the code, even though other compilers will gladly accept it. In particular the quote would be within §14.6[temp.res]/8

> [...] If no valid specialization can be generated for a template definition, and that template is not instantiated, the template definition is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. [...] If a type used in a non-dependent name is incomplete at the point at which a template is defined but is complete at the point at which an instantiation is done, and if the completeness of that type affects whether or not the program is well-formed or affects the semantics of the program, the program is ill-formed; [...]

That is, the template is *ill-formed* although the compiler is not required to diagnose it.

Comment: Could you please clarify it a bit: *both* clang and gcc exhibit correct behaviour, eventhough one of them rejects this program and other one successfully compiles it?

Comment: @Nya: Yes, the program is *ill-formed*, so clang is right in rejecting it. But no diagnostic is required, so gcc is right in ignoring the issue. That does not mean that the program is right, only that gcc did not diagnose the error. To some extent this would be the equivalent to *undefined behavior* at compile time. It might seem to *work* although it is incorrect. Note that there are many cases where compilers are not required to diagnose, for example, two different definitions of an `inline` template is a violation of the ODR, but compilers are not required to diagnose (and most don't do)